# The amount of texts Irene sent in A Scandal in Belgravia?

Tags: sherlock

In the BBC Sherlock series, in A Scandal in Belgravia, Irene Adler's texts are shown on the screen near the end as she scrolls through them. But, if her texts are counted there are 16 while on the first day of her texting Sherlock, Watson states, "Fifty-seven of those texts – the ones I've heard." Has there been a mistake?

Comment: Why do you think all her texts were shown? Could ther not be 42 others she sent which were not shown?

Answer (score 2):

Obviously we don't see on screen every single instance when Doctor John Hamish Watson heard Irene's text alert. It's also similar to how we don't actually see every single murder Sherlock has solved. But when little Archie says, "Have you solved any murders?" And Sherlock replies, "Yup, loads." We don't just assume that the only murders he could have solved are the ones we saw on screen.